# generic types in dao in spring application

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, generics, morphia

i'm trying to launch spring application with morphia framework to create some web-app that works with mongodb

well, i have some abstract entity

```spring
public abstract class AbstractEntity {
    @Id
    protected ObjectId id;
    // getters, setters
}
```

also i have some Abstract Dao for this abstract entity

```spring
public abstract class AbstractDao<T extends AbstractEntity> extends BasicDAO<T, ObjectId> {
    protected AbstractDao(Mongo mongo, Morphia morphia, String dbName) {
        super(mongo, morphia, dbName);
    }
    //some methods
}
```

also i have some Abstract action

```spring
public abstract class AbstractAction {
    protected ActionType actionType;
    protected int dynamicWeight;
    protected Date createDate;
    // getters, setters
}
```

i have some more specific entity, like action entity that stores in list some actions

```spring
public abstract class ActionEntity<T extends AbstractAction> extends AbstractEntity {
    protected List<T> actions;
    // getters, setters
}
```

actions can be likes, comments, etc and they have their own classes, like

```spring
public class LikeAction extends AbstractAction implements ICombinable { 
    protected ObjectId authorId;
    protected ObjectId sourceId;
    //getters, setters and overrided equals();
}
```

finally, i have entity for storing e.g. likes

```spring
public class LikeActionEntity extends ActionEntity<LikeAction> {    
}
```

and dao for such entity

```spring
public class LikeActionDao extends AbstractDao<LikeActionEntity> {
    protected LikeActionDao(Mongo mongo, Morphia morphia, String dbName) {
        super(mongo, morphia, dbName);
    }   
}
```

in application context i have such beans

```spring
<bean class="com.foo.app.dao.action.LikeActionDao" id="likeActionDao">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongo" index="0"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="morphia" index="1"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="database" index="2"/>
</bean>
<bean class="com.mongodb.Mongo" id="mongo">
    <constructor-arg value="127.0.0.1:27017" index="0" />
</bean>
<bean id="morphia" class="com.google.code.morphia.Morphia" />
<bean class="java.lang.String" id="database">
    <constructor-arg value="database" />
</bean>
```

but when i'm trying to run spring application i get next exception

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'likeActionDao' defined in class path resource [app-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class 
[com.foo.app.dao.action.LikeActionDao]: Constructor threw exception; nested 
exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: bad type, not parameterized...

what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that this is morhia [issue](https://code.google.com/p/morphia/issues/detail?can=2&q=244&colspec=ID%20Type%20Stars%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&id=244)

Try to not use AbstractDao and extend your LikeActionDao  from BasicDAO directly. 
Also try to make LikeActionEntity not parametrized.

Answer (score 0):

The config file you have is missing the configuration for database.,

```
<bean class="java.lang.String" id="database">
     <constructor-arg value="database" /> </bean>
```

You might want to define some value for it.

Comment: ok, i'm deleting likeActionDao bean from xml and trying to get database bean and it's works